# Integrating stripe api

Tags: android, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to use stripe payment gateway for my android app. This is my first time using this so bear with me here. I am following [this documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder) from stripe and there is line a where I am suppose to put my backend url in a variable like this

`private static final String BACKEND_URL = "my backend url";`

I am using Firebase for my back end and so my question is what will I put for the url?

Answer (score 0):

Your integration will look different if you use Firebase. Since you don't have a backend to connect to you'd want to look into using [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) instead.

You'd create the functions on Firebase (e.g. a "create PaymentIntent" function) and then call them directly from your [Firebase client on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#kotlin+ktx).